# Does OpenGL ES 1.1 try to render things that will not show up on screen?

Tags: iphone, optimization, opengl-es

I'm trying to determine if OpenGL ES 1.1 (Or 2.0, if there is a difference) will attempt to render anything that would fall outside of the viewable area.

Does it do a check to ensure that the actual rendering is needed before computing everything, or not? And if it does, where does this step occur? I haven't found much information on this subject at all.

Should I, while programming check to see whether an image should/will fall in (or very close to being in) the viewable area and only draw it if it is? Or will this be entirely redundant as OpenGL handles portions of this for me?

Or are there even OpenGL states that can be set to change the behavior here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't render anything outside of the framebuffer (assuming you have set the viewable area to the same size) as there is nothing to draw into. That counts for both, OpenGL ES 1.1 and 2.0.
However, you still push your data to the GPU and the data will be clipped, so you still waste time by letting your CPU waiting for the bus and the ok from the GPU. Better clip your stuff before you push the data to the GPU via OpenGL ES

Comment: And so you'd recommend making a very simple "radius" of half the longest side of the screen with the "radius" of the longest side of the image and see whether the distance between both centers is smaller than their two "radii" combined type of deal, here? And that this is a useful optimization so that I don't bottleneck waiting for the GPU to ok everything?

Comment: @Kevek: It really depends on what you are doing, but usually its really faster to do what you described then letting the GPU clip everything.